# JQPlot BarRenderer dates do not align with graph axis

Tags: html, css, jqplot

I have 2 graphs, the x axis grid of both graphs align but as you can see in the image below, the bar graph on the lower plot does not correlate to the x grid value. When the cursor is placed on the far right side of the bar it reads (22 May) but the grid is displaying (1 June) making the visual display 10 days inaccurate.

See Image here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8yt1DOnKzVkRG5lNzFyM3M5MUk/edit?usp=sharing

A bug for this has been raised more than 3 years ago but does not look like it has been resolved. [Link to Bug](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/242/date-x-axis-points-do-not-line-up-with) and I was wondering if anybody has a workaround at all?

Code for the top plot looks like this:
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
      pregnancyPlot = $.jqplot('pregnancyGraph', [[['2013-01-20 16:57',123,156,123,156],['2013-03-22 17:05',69,130,69,130],['2013-05-22 17:05',69,130,69,130],['2013-07-20 15:26',110,180,110,180],['2013-08-01 15:27',120,80,120,80],['2013-09-20 15:14',120,60,120,60],['2013-11-22 17:14',107,161,107,161],['2013-11-26 12:30',106,180,106,180]], [['2013-01-20 16:57',123],['2013-03-22 17:05',90],['2013-05-22 17:05',90],['2013-07-20 15:26',67],['2013-08-01 15:27',101],['2013-09-20 15:14',67],['2013-11-22 17:14',58],['2013-11-26 12:30',123]],[['2013-01-20 16:57', 83.40],['2013-03-22 17:05', 75.00],['2013-05-22 17:05', 75.00],['2013-08-01 15:27', 103.00],['2013-09-20 15:14', 102.00],['2013-11-22 17:14', 98.00],['2013-11-26 12:30', 200.00]], [['2013-01-20 16:57', 2.50, 4],['2013-03-22 17:05', 4.00, 4],['2013-05-22 17:05', 4.00, 4],['2013-09-20 15:14', 2.50, 4],['2013-11-22 17:14', 2.70, 4],['2013-11-26 12:30', 2.50, 4]]], {
          title:'Pregnancy Readings',
          height: 300,
          width: 600,
          gridPadding: {top:20, bottom:0, left:80, right:0},
          series: [     
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions:{candleStick:true, fillUpBody:true, fillDownBody:true, bodyWidth:4}, color:'red', label: 'B.P'},
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.LineRenderer, color: 'black', label: 'Pulse'},
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.LineRenderer, showLine:false, markerOptions: { style:'filledDiamond', size:'15' }, color: '#00006B', label: 'Weight'},
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.BubbleRenderer, yaxis:'y2axis', rendererOptions: {autoscaleBubbles: false, varyBubbleColors: false}, color: '#FFA319', label: 'SF Height'}
                  ],


            axesDefaults:{
              labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
              tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
              tickOptions: {
                  angle: -30,
                  fontSize: '10pt',
                  showMark: false,
              }
            },

            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    autoscale:false,
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    showTicks: false,
                  },

               yaxis:{
                    autoscale:false,
                    renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer
                },
                y2axis:{
                    autoscale:true,
                    label: 'SF Height',
                    renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                       alignTicks: true,
                    }
                },

          },

          legend: {
                show: true,
                placement: 'outside',
                location: 'nw'
            },

          highlighter: {
              show: true,
              showMarker: false,
              sizeAdjust: 7.5,
              yvalues: 2,
            },

            cursor: {
              show: true,
              zoom: true
            }
        });
    });
```

Code for the bottom plot (The one not aligned correctly) looks like this:
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
      urinePlot = $.jqplot('urineGraph', [[['2013-01-20', 50 ],['2013-07-20', 50 ],['2013-09-20', 50 ]], [['2013-03-22', 50 ],['2013-05-22', 50 ],['2013-11-22', 50 ],['2013-11-26', 50 ]]], {
          height: 100,
          width: 600,
          gridPadding: {top:0, bottom:60, left:80, right:0},
          series: [     
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer, rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true, barWidth: 15},  color: 'green', label: 'Unine Normal'},
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer, rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true, barWidth: 15},  color: 'red', label: 'Unine Abnormal'}
                  ],

                axesDefaults:{
                  labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                  tickOptions: {
                      angle: -30,
                      fontSize: '10pt',
                      showMark: false,
                  }
                },

            axes: {    

                 xaxis: {
                    autoscale:false,
                    label: '',
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions:{
                       formatString:'%d %b %Y'
                    }
                  },

                 yaxis:{
                        renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                        showTicks: false,
                    },
            },

            highlighter: {
                  show: true,
                  showMarker: false,
                  sizeAdjust: 7.5
                },

           legend: {
                    show: true,
                    placement: 'outside',
                    location: 'nw'
                },

            cursor: {
                  show: true,
                  zoom: true
                }

        });
    });
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the OHLCRenderer and got it to behave like the BarRenderer by setting the lower value to zero and the upper value to what would have been entered into the BarRenderer and set the body width.

Code for the top plot now looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

      pregnancyPlot = $.jqplot('pregnancyGraph', [[['2013-12-01 10:36',110,180,110,180],['2013-12-08 17:16',80,185,80,185]], [['2013-12-01 10:36',123],['2013-12-08 17:16',67]],[['2013-12-01 10:36', 105.00],['2013-12-08 17:16', 105.00]], [['2013-12-01 10:36', 2.50, 4],['2013-12-08 17:16', 2.70, 4]]], {
          title:'Pregnancy Readings',
          height: 300,
          width: 600,
          gridPadding: {top:20, bottom:0, left:80, right:0},
          series: [     
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions:{candleStick:true, fillUpBody:true, fillDownBody:true, bodyWidth:4}, color:'red', label: 'B.P'},
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.LineRenderer, color: 'black', label: 'Pulse'},
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.LineRenderer, showLine:false, markerOptions: { style:'filledDiamond', size:'15' }, color: '#00006B', label: 'Weight'},
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.BubbleRenderer, yaxis:'y2axis', rendererOptions: {autoscaleBubbles: false, varyBubbleColors: false}, color: '#FFA319', label: 'SF Height'}
                  ],


            axesDefaults:{
              labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
              tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
              tickOptions: {
                  angle: -30,
                  fontSize: '10pt',
                  showMark: false,
              }
            },

            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    min:'2013-11-28',
                    max:'2013-12-11',
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    showTicks: false,
                  },

               yaxis:{
                    autoscale:false,
                    renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer
                },
                y2axis:{
                    autoscale:true,
                    label: 'SF Height',
                    renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                       alignTicks: true,
                    }
                },

          },

          legend: {
                show: true,
                placement: 'outside',
                location: 'nw'
            },

          highlighter: {
              show: true,
              showMarker: false,
              sizeAdjust: 7.5,
              yvalues: 2,
            },

            cursor: {
              show: true,
              zoom: true
            }
        });
    });
```

Code for the bottom plot (Now aligned correctly) looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

      urinePlot = $.jqplot('urineGraph', [[['2013-12-01 10:36', 0,50,0,50]], [['2013-12-08 17:16', 0,50,0,50]]], {
          height: 100,
          width: 600,
          gridPadding: {top:0, bottom:60, left:80, right:0},
          series: [     
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions:{candleStick:true, fillUpBody:true, fillDownBody:true, bodyWidth:15},  color: 'green', label: 'Urine Normal'},
                        {renderer:$.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions:{candleStick:true, fillUpBody:true, fillDownBody:true, bodyWidth:15},  color: 'red', label: 'Urine Abnormal'}
                  ],

                axesDefaults:{
                  labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                  tickOptions: {
                      angle: -30,
                      fontSize: '10pt',
                      showMark: false,
                  }
                },

            axes: {    

                 xaxis: {
                    min:'2013-11-28',
                    max:'2013-12-11',
                    label: '',
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions:{
                       formatString:'%d %b %Y'
                    }
                  },

                 yaxis:{
                        min:0,
                        max:50,
                        renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                        showTicks: false,
                    },
            },

            highlighter: {
                  show: true,
                  showMarker: false,
                  sizeAdjust: 7.5
                },

           legend: {
                    show: true,
                    placement: 'outside',
                    location: 'nw'
                },

            cursor: {
                  show: true,
                  zoom: true
                }

        });
    });
```